# Exportar archivo .csv con acentos y especiales, desde datos de TSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, acentos

Tengo una aplicación en en **MVC** con **BD** en **TSQL**. Al momento de exportar mis clientes, los acentos se están destruyendo.

```
    public ActionResult DownloadClients()
    {
        var franchiseId = User.Identity.Name.GetFranchiseIdFromSession();
        var franchise = _franchiseRepository.Get(franchiseId);
        var header = string.Empty;
        var auxClient = new Client();
        foreach (var property in auxClient.DownloadableHeaders())
        {
            header += property + ",";
        }

        var csv = header + Environment.NewLine;
        var clients = _clientRepository.GetByFranchise(franchiseId);

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            var date = "N/A";
            if (client.Created.HasValue)
                date = client.Created.Value.ToShortDateString();

            var line = client.Name + "," + client.ZipCargoId + "," + client.Cellphone + "," +
                    client.Email + "," + "\"" + client.Address + "\"" + "," + 
                    client.Membership.Name + date;

            csv += line + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        var dateFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        var ascii = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv);
        var utf8 = ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, Encoding.Default, ascii);

        return File(utf8, "text/csv", dateFormat + "Clientes" + franchise.Name + ".csv");
    }
```

Cuando el archivo se descarga tengo el siguiente problema con algunos caracteres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa la codificación con la que creas el csv debe ser UTF8

Comment: Para mostrar acentos en ASCII tienes que usar un codepage que los tenga. Por ejemplo Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252") sería el del español para el Excel. Si lo cambias yo creo que ya te debería funcionar sin problema. Y no necesitarias la linea de que convierte a utf-8, que es donde te los está cambiando por un ?

Comment: @bsebe, Hola acabo de revisar esto de nuevo y me encontré con tu respuesta, y es la correcta. Mil gracias.